# What to call drum player VSTs as opposed to drum machines?

Tags: practice, drums, vst, reason, drum-machine

On the one hand, there are drum machines/sequencers/loopers/programmers etc that combines a drum machine and a fairly static drum loop that you play or sequence yourself.

Then there are 'superset' products like https://shop.propellerheads.se/product/a-list-studio-drummer/ that does that plus some degree of dynamic variations (I didn't buy it yet, just as far as I can tell from reading about it) that plays a bit more like an accompanying band member if you're practicing alone, provided you give it some hints via MIDI keys.

What do you call the latter class of products? A drum player? How do I search for more products like it?

The end goal is to have an improvisation practice tool for other instruments so I don't have to pre-emptively program individual drum notes or drum measures or drum songs nor live hint drum measures but live hint song sections. Like play dynamic pattern 1 with frequency x of fills with intensity y. I press a button and it goes to pattern 2. I press another button and it launches into 4 bars of increased intensity followed by an automatic bridge type pattern.

Comment: I guess the physical device equivalent would be https://singularsound.com/. Seems a bit incomplete to just call them drum machines.

Comment: The only other thing I know of that does something like that is Apple Garage Band. There might not be a name for those things, since there aren't that many of them out there. Perhaps "virtual drummer" software.